# Is there a better way to get inherited properties from a base class fast to an inherited class than using a base class by injection?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

The essence of my problem is that there is a serialized object coming from a database that I parse.  I will have int and DateTime fields as well as others.  I have the equivalent of four different subtypes of the base type.  So think of it as they each have different fields but share the Id and DateCreated.  I want to save time and rather than have a long constructor to insert all these values just do something like:

```
var base = new BaseTest(101, DateTime.Now.Date);
X inherited = (X)base;
```

But of course, that's a no no in .NET so I wonder - could I just use the BaseClass as a full-on DTO object for injection?  Yes I can do that,  But it doesn't pass the smell test with me.  Something about it seems off, and I feel that I am solving a problem the wrong way so I was curious if anyone had a better idea.  The end goal is to just reuse an Id and DateTime field that could be done before I know what the SubType object is and then just feed that in somehow without a long constructor.  So far I have this:

```
public class BaseTest
  {
    public int BaseId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public BaseTest() { }

    public BaseTest(int baseId, DateTime created)
    {
      BaseId = baseId;
      Created = created;
    }
  }

  public class X : BaseTest
  {
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public int Val { get; set; }

    public X(string desc, int val, BaseTest baseValues)
    {
      Desc = desc;
      Val = val;
      BaseId = baseValues.BaseId;
      Created = baseValues.Created;
    }
  }


  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //This works for a reuse pattern but just doesn't feel right.
      var b = new BaseTest(101, DateTime.Now.Date);
      var p = new X("Test", 1, b);

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

I could change the constructor to something like:

```
public X(string desc, int val, int baseId, DateTime created) : base(baseId, created)
{
  Desc = desc;
  Val = val;
}
```

But then I am making a long constructor.  So really I guess I am curious if the language could do narrowing scope from a base class to an inherited to assume it's properties but I don't think it can.

Comment: Just for setting r/w properties you do not need a constructor at all, just use new X{ BaseId = 1, ... }

Comment: @SirRufo Yeah I realize that.  What I am after is more if a transmutation is possible or a DTO equivalent to do four or five in a single swoop.  Sort of like: "Okay I made my parent object up and know it's four properties.  Now that it exists can I re use that for injection into if it's instance A, B, C, Or D."  instead of doing A(int val){ BaseId = baseId, DateTime = created}, B(decimal val, string desc) {BaseId = baseId, DateTime = created}.  I'm just trying to avoid doing repeat calls if I already have the info.  Might not be possible what I am thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this same issue with some VB.NET code for work, and I satisfied it by having each class have a "convenience initialization constructor" (there's *probably* a better term for this, IIRC it's a copy constructor in C++). I've yet to find a way to truly transfigure, as you mention (someone far smarter than I probably has one), but I've come up with the aforementioned idea (example below) to help keep my stress-level down.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Foo() {}
    public Foo(Foo foo) { Id = foo.Id; }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Bar(Foo foo, string name) : base(foo) { Name = name; }
    public Bar(Bar bar) : base(bar) { Name = bar.Name; } // Allows further inheritance
}
```

This creates a *small* maintainability deficit: you have two *mostly* identical constructors, but it allows you to do things like:

```
var foo = new Foo() { Id = 5 }
// Decide that `foo` should now be a `Bar`
var bar = new Bar(foo, "John");
```

In this way, `Bar` really doesn't need to know about the internals of `Foo`, just that it can be built from a `Foo` and additional properties. This also has the curious side-effect of allowing a `Bar` to be built from the `Foo` properties of a `Baz`:

```
public class Baz : Foo
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public Baz(Foo foo, DateTime birthDate) : base(foo) { BirthDate = birthDate; }
    public Baz(Baz baz) : base(baz) { BirthDate = baz.BirthDate; } // Allows further inheritance
}
```

> ```
> var foo = new Foo() { Id = 5 };
> var bar = new Bar(foo, "John");
> var baz = new Baz(bar, DateTime.UtcNow);
> ```

Finally, you could even omit the additional parameters from the `Bar(Foo foo, ...)` constructor, and use the property initialization syntax (`new Bar(foo) { Name = "John" }`), but that decision is left to you.